# Understanding IO methods and objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, io

I am learning Ruby by following [learnrubythehardway](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex17.html) and it seems very easy and straightforward until you are asked to explain what certain things do. I have commented in my code what I believe is happening in the program. Wanted to see if I am on target, need to rethink things or have no clue and should stop trying to learn how to code.

```
# Sets variables to arguments sent through terminal
from_file, to_file = ARGV

# Saves from_file object into in_file
in_file = open(from_file)
puts in_file

# Saves from_file data into indata
indata = in_file.read
puts indata

# Save to_file object into out_file with writing privileages
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
puts out_file

# Writes(copies) indata into out_file
out_file.write(indata)

# Closes files so they can not be accessed anymore
out_file.close
in_file.close
```

This is what the output in the terminal looks like:

```
#<File:0x0000000201b038>
This is text from the ex17_from.txt file.
Did it copy to the ex17_to.txt file?
#<File:0x0000000201ae58>
```

We are also given the task to try to reduce the amount of code needed and are told that we can do this entire action in one line of code. I figured I can just erase out all of the comments and puts statements, while everything else is put into one line of code. However, that will be one long line and I don't think that is what the author is asking for. Any ideas on how to shorten this code will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> I have commented in my code what I believe is happening in the program. Wanted to see if I am on target, need to rethink things or have no clue

You need to learn to see beyond the written words. For example, this comment is pretty useless:

```
# Saves from_file object into in_file
in_file = open(from_file)
```

Not only useless, but actually incorrect. What is this `from_file` object? What kind of object will `in_file` be? Why don't you mention `open` in any way?

What actually happens here is that a File/IO object is created by calling `open`. And `from_file`, in this case, is a **path to file**. Not much of an "object", is it? But `in_file` is a full File object, which you can use to read the file's contents.

The same goes for the rest of your comments. You simply reword the line of code with human words, without describing the *intent* behind the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So learn how to describe the intent, got it. Comments always through me off, but now I can see it's because I'm throwing myself off. Do you know of any good references that describes all computer terminology. I read through ruby-doc.org documentation and it seems straight forward. But comprehending it seems to be a bit harder for me. My guess is I need to become more familiar with what everything means and how it works.

Comment: @limaBEAN: yes, exactly, you just need more experience and more familiarity with the stdlib (which method does what, etc.) When you encounter a method call you don't know, go read its documentation. This is what I do and it worked pretty well so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileUtils#cp`, and do the following:

```
require "fileutils"
FileUtils.cp *ARGV
```

`*` splats the `ARGV` array into two parameters needed by `cp` method

---

Alternatively, below is concise version of your code:

```
# Sets variables to arguments sent through terminal
from_file, to_file = ARGV

# Saves from_file object into to_file
open(to_file, 'w') do |out|
  open(from_file) do |f|
      f.each do |line|
        out << line
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great alternative solution. I have been trying to use do blocks, but I'm never sure if it's allowed. So I just end up following through the tutorial. How do you decide when to use do blocks and when not to? Are there certain times when I will always need to use a do block? Or is it do whatever you want, it's just code?